# ¿Que sucede al evaluarse esta condicion x < z?, ¿Porque no se cumplen al tomar los valores por input()? (python)

Tags: python, condiciones

Estoy aprendiendo un poco sobre python con un libro (Python para todos) y me encontré con este detalle. Quiero comparar dos números cualesquiera, X y Z, tomo sus valores por consolas y luego imprimo por consola diciendo quien es mayor a quien o si son iguales. Y sucede que al evaluar por ejemplo, *X = 10 y Z = 6*, toma la condición de que X es menor a Z.

```
x = input("valor x: ")
z = input("valor z: ")

print('El valor de x es: ' + x)
print('El valor de z es: ' + z)

if x > z:
    print('x es mayor que z')
elif x < z:
    print('x es menor que z')
else:
    print('x y z son iguales')
```

Se supone que para este caso debería imprimirse el mensaje

> x es mayor que z

Pero se salta esa condición y toma  la siguiente

> x es menor que z

Me siento extraño preguntando algo tan básico, pero la verdad no encuentro solución. Cabe destacar que lo impreso por pantalla por los comandos print luego de tomar los valores X y Z reflejan que son *X:10 y Z:6*, lo cual me dice que esta tomando los valores correctamente

> print('El valor de x es: ' + x)

Cabe destacar que si intento lo siguiente las condiciones se cumplen perfectamente

```
x = 10
z = 6

print('El valor de x es: ' + x)
print('El valor de z es: ' + z)

if x > z:
    print('x es mayor que z')
elif x < z:
    print('x es menor que z')
else:
    print('x y z son iguales')
```

Comment: Todo parece indicar que te los está evaluando como string, debes hacer un cast a enteros, lee aquí https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int

Comment: Es tal cual lo que dice @BetaM. Prueba a escribir `"6" < "10"` y luego `6 < 10`. El primero es falso y el segundo cierto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `input()` retorna un `str` cuando lo que este script requiere es que estos valores sean `int`:

```
x = int(input("valor x: "))
z = int(input("valor z: "))
```

Lo mismo sería cierto para el caso de requerir `float`. Para casos simples va a "funcionar" ya que al comparar si `'2' < '3'`, estarás comparando los códigos ASCII (UTF-8, realmente) de estos dos valores, que están en orden. Para para `str` que representen números de dos o más dígitos los resultados no serán los esperados.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo agregarle el tipo de dato a tus líneas para intentar reconocer el error que mencionan en los comentarios:

```
x = input("valor x: ")
z = input("valor z: ")
print('El valor de x es: ' + x + ' y es del tipo: ' + str(type(x)))
print('El valor de z es: ' + z + ' y es del tipo: ' + str(type(z)))
if x > z:
   print('x es mayor que z')
elif x < z:
    print('x es menor que z')
else:
     print('x y z son iguales')
```

Comment: Bueno pero una cosa es que identifique el tipo de dato, pero ¿luego como lo transforma?

Comment: No quería ir directo a la solución pero la misma esta en el casteo propio de mi respuesta: utilizar int() para convetir el input str en int o bien... raw_input para python 2.x, no esta disponible en Python 3.x